# Distributive laws and Absorption laws with negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I'm currently stumped because I can't seem to find a way though this proof I'm currently doing. I did notice because of this proof that I'm really not sure how to handle these two situations...

1) A situation where it looks like I can use absorption laws, but there's negation like so: $(p ∧ q) ∨ ¬p$

2) A situation where it looks like I can use distributive laws, but there's negation like so : $(p ∧ q) ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬r)$

Any clarification is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Absorption law cannot be applied.
   That is because not-p is neither p nor q.
   Use distributive law.
2. Distributive can be used.
   Consider not-p as s and not-r as t and apply distributivity.
   Afterwards return s to not-p and t to not-r.